# How do I rename XElement Name using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have multiple tags in my XML like, `<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>`. So I want to rename each one as `<span class="ld_bold">`, `<span class="ld_italic">` and `<span class="ld_underline">` respectively.

Currently I am doing this using `foreach` but I want to use `LINQ`.

Following is my approach:

```
foreach (var item in xdoc.Descendants("b"))
{
    item.Name = "span";
    item.SetAttributeValue("class", "ld_bold");
}

foreach (var item in xdoc.Descendants("i"))
{
    item.Name = "span";
    item.SetAttributeValue("class", "ld_italic");
}

foreach (var item in xdoc.Descendants("u"))
{
    item.Name = "span";
    item.SetAttributeValue("class", "ld_underline");
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
xdoc.Descendants().Where(el => el.InnerXml().Contains("<b>")).Select(x => x).ToList()
                  .ForEach(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("span") && x.SetAttributeValue("class", "ld_bold"));
```

In the `LINQ`, I am getting an error in the `ForEach` section.

Comment: you getting an error because Foreach is a counting expression, gettin an Action delegate. So, Try something like this: xdoc.Descendants().Where(el => el.InnerXml().Contains("<b>")).Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("span")).ToList().ForEach(x => x.SetAttributeValue("class", "ld_bold"));

Comment: The solution looks like it will set the attribute to all the elements containing `<span>` but I am replacing each tag with a `<span>` and it's respective `attribute`. So, I want to change `Name` and set the `attribute` at the same time.

Comment: Ah, okay. So, try this: xdoc.Descendants().Where(el => el.InnerXml().Contains("<b>")).ToList().ForEach(x => { x.Name.LocalName = "span"; x.SetAttributeValue("class", "ld_bold"); });

Comment: @Dmitriy - Works perfectly :). Appreciate it. Just a very minor change, the `LINQ` will not accept `Name.LocalName`, `.Name` is working and that is what worked.

Comment: Nope, glad to help you)

Comment: "I am getting an error in ..." - always post the full error message(s).